# Открыть страницу сайта только 1 раз

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Описываю ситуацию: есть сайт, похожий на квиз. идет порядок страниц (на каждой есть кнопка "далее", которая открывает следующую):

1. home.html
2. reg.html
3. modal-1.html
4. ticket.html
5. wait.html

Нужно сделать так, чтобы при первом посещении пользователь прошел все страницы сайта, а при повторном посещении сразу после страницы `home` шла страница `wait`.

Грубо говоря, при повторном посещении "отключить" страницы 2-4. в интернете нашел информацию, что это делается с помощью сессий, но не нашел решения своей проблемы.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Такой функционал будет проще всего сделать с помощью JavaScript и хранилища `localStorage`. Когда юзер пройдёт все шаги, мы запишем ему такой ключ:

```
localStorage.setItem('notFirstSession', true)
```

Затем мы можем проверить, установлен ли этот ключ у юзера, и если да, то сделаем редирект на нужную страницу:

```
const userSession = localStorage.getItem('notFirstSession')

if (userSession) {
    window.location.href = '/wait.html'
}
```

Comment: скажите, пожалуйста, в какое место вставлять ваш код?

Comment: @Матвей я же не знаю, какой у вас код. Адаптируйте его под свои нужны.

Comment: "localStorage.setItem('firstSession', true)" необходимо поставить на последней странице сайта?

Comment: @Матвей да,  если хотите, чтобы юзер прошел все шаги.

Comment: извиняюсь, задам ещё один вопрос: этот код `const
    userSession = localStorage.getItem('notFirstSession')

if (userSession) {
    window.location.href = '/wait.html'
}`
 нужно поставить на каждой странице?

Comment: спасибо большое! разобрался, вопрос решён

Comment: @Матвей пожалуйста! Извините, отходил и не мог ответить сразу. Но хорошо, что сами разобрались)